# How to GET JSON array from REST API in JAva?

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, rx-java

I am using a REST API to retrieve info from a database.

I am able to retrieve a Cosmetic object ( a class I created ) but what I really want to do is make a search which should retrieve an array of Cosmetics.

Making a request to the API with a browser/Insomnia, I get a JSON array of Objects (Cosmetics), like this:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"6353e8fe5d63726919402cec",
      "code":"0000016615656",
           -- omitted --
   },
   {
      "_id":"6353e8fe5d63726919402cec",
      "code":"0000016615656",
           -- omitted --
   }
]
```

I managed to make it work for one Cosmetic object:

**I have declared a class that is a POJO with the attributes as such:**

```
public class Cosmetic implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
         ---- omitted ----
}
```

And **then I use retrofit and RxJava to make the API calls.**

```
final Cosmetic[] cosmetic_result = new Cosmetic[1];
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

service = retrofit.create(CosmeticsService.class);

// Calling '/prod/beauty/{field}'
Single<Cosmetic> callSync = service.getByName(query);

CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
callSync.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        //https://www.baeldung.com/rxjava-error-handling
        .onErrorReturn(Throwable -> productNotFound)
        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Cosmetic>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                compositeDisposable.add(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Cosmetic cosmetic) {
                System.out.println("API has responded ");
                result[0] = cosmetic.getCode();
                cosmetic_result[0]=cosmetic;
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
// While loop necessary to force waiting for the API result
while(result[0]==""){} // DON'T DELETE

return cosmetic_result[0];
```

So this works for one JSON object as such:

```
{
   "_id":"6353e8fe5d63726919402cec",
   "code":"0000016615656"
        --- omitted ---
}
```

**How do I go about doing this in Java for an array?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using HttpURLConnection but I don't know how safe this is.
I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/getting-json-data-from-a-restful-api-using-java-b327aafb3751), which I recommend!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not link to external resources for a solution, except additional information on wiki pages and documentation.
Refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidline to improve your contribution.